# before(){ browser.maximizeWindow(); } in wdio.conf.ts.It shows can not find any browser

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, webdriver-io

I am currently working on WEBDRIVER IO Using TYPESCRIPT  in VS code.I am using this  before(){     browser.maximizeWindow();     }  in wdio.conf.ts.It shows can not find any browser. It maximises the browser on run time. But in code it still shows can not find any browser. Not sure where the problem lies. Below is the screenshot of tsconfig.file
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added `"./wdio.conf.ts"` to `include` array in tsconfig.json

Comment: Thank you Mike. You made my Friday. This works now. I have added 
"include": ["./features/**/*.ts","./wdio.conf.ts"]

Answer (score 0):

Move it to the beforeSuite, it'll work fine:  `beforeSuite: function (suite) { browser.maximizeWindow(); }`